# regsvr32 doesn't register my library as COM without dotnet 5 sdk

Tags: .net, regsvr32

regsvr32 doesn't register my library as COM without dotnet sdk
I try to register my Library.comhost.dll as COM in registry, but without dotnet sdk I have issue

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iELyE.png)

After .net 5 sdk was installed my library was appeared in registry,

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfHf2.png)

Also I found out that I don't need all libraries from dotnet folder

The folder hierarchy with dlls which placed inside are enough to successfully registration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlQ9z.png)

My question: Potentially I don't want to download and install sdk for end consumers. So I need workaround for case without install sdk.

Do we have some workaround for my case or maybe some guesses about what I do wrong?

Please let me know about additional details from my side to help me

Answer (score 0):

the answer is existing in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

Also you can see discussion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/495499/regsvr32-doesn39t-register-my-library-as-com-witho.html